# mongo-join is not working in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i am using mongo-join to join two collections in node.js. Below code shows that query but its not joining two collections. Somebody please help me.

### something.js

```
var client = new Db(config.dbname, new Server(config.host, config.port1));
            client.open(function(err, client) {
                client.collection('proInfo', function(err, proInfo) {
                    proInfo.find({}, function(err, cursor) {
                        var join = new Join(client).on({
                            field: '_id', // <- field in proInfo doc 
                            to: 'purchasedItemId',// <- field in purchased doc. treated as ObjectID automatically. 
                            from: 'purchased'  // <- collection name for purchased doc 
                        });   
                        join.toArray(cursor, function(err, joinedDocs) {
                        // handle array of joined documents here 
                        console.log(joinedDocs);
                        });


                    });
                });  
            });
```

Two collections are,

### proInfo collection

`{
   "_id"▼: ObjectId("573337d73e102e40365bb5db"),
   "Product_Name": "KRISONS BLUETOOTH 5.1 MULTIMEDIA SPEAKER HOME THEATER SYSTEM",
   "Brand": "Krisons",
   "Color": "",
   "Image": "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41H6cuSsemL._SY300_QL70_.jpg",
   "Price": "2,690.00",
   "Rating": "3.6 out of 5 stars",
   "Description": "Krisons 5.1 Speaker System has various input sources like Bluetooth, USB ,FM Radio , AUX-IN and SD Card reader and is compatible with your Mobile Phon [...]",
   "Category": "Electronics",
   "Url": "http://www.amazon.in/KRISONS-BLUETOOTH-MULTIMEDIA-SPEAKER-THEATER/dp/B019FR8ZYQ/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1462974388&sr=1-1",
   "userId": ObjectId("570dec75cf30bf4c09679deb"),
   "purchased": "yes",
   "contributed": "" 
}`

### purchased collection

`{
   "_id": ObjectId("5734534d242223b40d9bbe3c"),
   "quantity": "2",
   "store": "amazon",
   "purchasedPerson": "vinay",
   "email": "vinay@gmail.com",
   "message": "I purchased this item for you",
   "terms": "yes",
   "purchasedItemID": "573337d73e102e40365bb5db",
   "purchasedDate": "2016-05-12T09:54:37.916Z",
   "ownerId": "570dec75cf30bf4c09679deb" 
}`